# Rational Numbers: Ordering equality question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ordering of rationals:

$(b \gt 0 \land d \gt 0) \implies ((\frac a b \lt \frac c d) \iff ad \lt bc)$

Why does the inequality hold?

I understand the algebra of multiplying by $b,d$ on both sides, which equals the RHS of $\iff$.  I understand that the equality should hold where $\frac a b = \frac c d \iff ad = bc$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication by a positive number preserves inequalities.